# Error on deploying Flask API with Spotipy package to Cloud

Tags: python, rest, flask, google-cloud-platform, spotipy

I wrote this Flask API in order to interact with my app's front-end and the Spotify API. Locally, the API runns fine however when I try to deploy it to Google Cloud and run it, the following error from the Spotipy package shows up:

```
"POST /createPlaylist" 500
ERROR in app: Exception on /createPlaylist [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 115, in _get_user_input      return raw_input(prompt)
           ^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app      response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 43, in create_playlist
    creation_response = sp.user_playlist_create(
         ...
```

I did some research on this and I found this GitHub example to adapt the API for the server: https://github.com/spotipy-dev/spotipy/blob/master/examples/app.py, however, couldn't solve the issue.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, jsonify, session
from flask_session import Session
import os
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth, SpotifyClientCredentials
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from interactions import (
    filterTracks,
    generateCustomTitle,
    generateNewTracksForReinforcement,
)

app = Flask(__name__)


scopes = [
    "ugc-image-upload",
    "playlist-read-private",
    "playlist-read-collaborative",
    "playlist-modify-public",
    "playlist-modify-private",
]

client_id_var = os.getenv("SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID")
client_secret_var = os.getenv("SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET")

client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(
    client_id=client_id_var, client_secret=client_secret_var
)

app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

sp = spotipy.Spotify(
    client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager,
    auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(
        client_id=client_id_var,
        client_secret=client_secret_var,
        redirect_uri="https://sound-scout-flask-api.nw.r.appspot.com/callback",
        scope=scopes,
        show_dialog=True,
        cache_handler=spotipy.FlaskSessionCacheHandler(app),
    ),
)


@app.route("/")
def sign_in():
    auth_url = sp.auth_manager.get_authorize_url()
    return redirect(auth_url)


@app.route("/callback")
def callback():
    sp.auth_manager.get_access_token(request.args.get("code"))
    return redirect("https://sound-scout-flask-api.nw.r.appspot.com/createPlaylist")


@app.route("/createPlaylist", methods=["POST"])
def create_playlist():
    data = request.get_json()
    promptAnswer = data.get("promptAnswer")
    playlistSubject = data.get("playlistSubject")
    playlistTitle = generateCustomTitle(promptAnswer).replace('"', "")
    tracks = filterTracks(promptAnswer)

    user_id = sp.current_user()["id"]  # Get current user's ID

    creation_response = sp.user_playlist_create(
        user=user_id,
        name=playlistTitle,
        public=False,
        collaborative=True,
        description=playlistSubject,
    )

    if creation_response:
        playlist_id = creation_response["id"]
        playlistURL = creation_response["external_urls"]["spotify"]

        track_ids = getTrackIds(tracks)

        result_url = addTrackToPlaylist(playlist_id, playlistURL, track_ids)

        reinforcePlaylistResults(playlistURL, 15, promptAnswer, playlistSubject)

        return jsonify({"playlistURL": result_url}), 200
    else:
        return jsonify({"error": "Playlist creation failed"}), 400


def getTrackId(track_name: str, track_artist: str):
  ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I think this is a Python2 and Python3 related sure. As far as I know `raw_input` was supported in Python2, which is replaced with `input` in Python3. Which version of Python are you working on ?

Comment: @ZdaR Python3. I'll re-run the env and change the Python version to see if it works. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: 1: You need code for the Authorization code flow. 2: You are trying to use two auth managers in one command: `sp=spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager,auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=client_id_var,…`, and that's a mistake.